# Is the FilterKeys feature in Microsoft Windows 7 supposed to prevent accidental repeated keystrokes?

Tags: windows-7, filterkeys

Is the [FilterKeys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FilterKeys) feature in Microsoft Windows 7 supposed to prevent accidental repeated keystrokes?

When I turn it on, it doesn't seem to work:

[image]

The same behavior happens not just in the text box, but anywhere else as well.

What could be the issue?

I used Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instead turn "Bounce keys" on, so that it ignores any repeated keystrokes:

[image]